# How to round corners of this custom shape SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes, rounded-corners

I used this tutorial to create a hexagon shape:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-draw-polygons-and-stars

My goal is to try to round the corners of my hexagon shape. I know I have to use the path.addCurve somehow, but I cannot figure out where I need to do that. I am only getting weird results. Has anyone got an idea?

```
struct Polygon: Shape {
    let corners: Int
    let smoothness: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard corners >= 2 else { return Path() }
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
        var currentAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
        let angleAdjustment = .pi * 2 / CGFloat(corners * 2)
        let innerX = center.x * smoothness
        let innerY = center.y * smoothness
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x * cos(currentAngle), y: center.y * sin(currentAngle)))

        var bottomEdge: CGFloat = 0

        for corner in 0 ..< corners * 2 {
            let sinAngle = sin(currentAngle)
            let cosAngle = cos(currentAngle)
            let bottom: CGFloat

            if corner.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                bottom = center.y * sinAngle
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: center.x * cosAngle, y: bottom))
            } else {
                bottom = innerY * sinAngle
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: innerX * cosAngle, y: bottom))
            }

            if bottom > bottomEdge {
                bottomEdge = bottom
            }
            currentAngle += angleAdjustment
        }

        let unusedSpace = (rect.height / 2 - bottomEdge) / 2
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: center.x, y: center.y + unusedSpace)
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}

struct Hexagon: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
            Polygon(corners: 3, smoothness: 1)
                .fill(.clear)
                .frame(width: 76, height: 76)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a modifier that does it: `.strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, lineJoin: .round))`.

Comment: When I use that, my hexagon completely brakes :/

Comment: Edit your question and show how you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't found a fix but this library does what I want:
https://github.com/heestand-xyz/PolyKit

Comment: Thanks for sharing Lucas. Quick question (as I'm new to SwiftUI), do you have an idea how to apply a border line with + color with polykit?

Comment: Does this work for you?
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-draw-a-border-around-a-view

Comment: Sadly no, already tried. It only gives a rect border, instead of the shape border

Comment: Okay, in theory I guess you could render it two times one bigger and smaller and layer them over each other

Comment: Ha, this was also my workaround for now. I created an issue at the GitHub lib.